# crashing app when using std::vector in multithreaded C++ program

Tags: c++, multithreading

Simplified:
I am writing plugins to realbasic. I have two plugins with their own threads. Everything is fine until i start to use std::vector. I have vector<> variables in both plugins and I am not using the vectors to use same data or to share data between threads or anything else. My model looks like this:

```
thread_1{
    vector<> variable_1;
    foreach{
         variable_1.push_back(something);
    }
}


thread_2{
    vector<> variable_2;
    foreach{
         variable_2.push_back(something);
    }
}
```

If I don't declare the vectors static, the program most of the times crashes. But even when i declare the variables static, and use some of algorithms like sort or copy, the crashes appear again.
It seems like the operations on vector are using some abstract class which is not multithread safe or something. Or am I doing something wrong?
Thank you.

I am using windows 7 x64, visual studio 2008 pro, compilation on release win32.

Comment: Perhaps the copy constructor for `something` is not thread safe?

Comment: Could you put the real code ? With what you posted, it is impossible to know if it comes from the multithreading situation or not.

Comment: I agree with the above comment about copy constructors. Reference counters that get modified asynchronously is a classical problem I believe.

Comment: You mentioned plugins, are they built by one project in a single binary? Or some kind of `dll`s?

Comment: SRY, the "something" is not the same class or type. I ment that variable_1 can be for example int and variable_2 of type double.

Comment: The problem is that i cant show entire code because it is too complex. The plugins are in DLLs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the allocator is not thread safe. You should either allocate vector (reserve) in a thread safe way or use a thread safe allocator.